# jQuery checking each element against each other element in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

(ty putvande and shanet for pointing out the wrong ')' which now is removed, I had however to repost the question as it only got answers related to that little mistake and not the main question)

I'm having a lot of difficulties constructing the following in javascript:

FOR every element with `Assemble_station` `class`

CHECK whether it overlaps with each other element with `Assemble_station` `class`

IF it does: CHECK which element has biggest left position of the two, move the element with the biggest left position to another location to avoid collision

Here's what I've written

```
$(".Assemble_station").each(function (i, firstobj) {
    $(".Assemble_station").each(function (i, secondobj) {
        if ($(firstobj).overlaps($(".Assemble_station").not(firstobj), secondobj)) {
            if ($(firstobj).css("left") >= $(secondobj).css("left")) {
                $(secondobj).css("top", "98px");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle that uses the code at the back: http://jsfiddle.net/NxWxU/6/

**To sum up the question, I'm trying to find the best practice method for doing what I described above. And so far I don't get why my current code isn't even working. >.<**

You can see that some of the elements clearly overlap if you break my code in jsfiddle and watch their positions before the are moved to same vertical position.

Ty for taking the time to try help

Comment: You should seriously check your console sometimes, like for your previous question. Problem here seems to be you want to apply to a jquery object a method overlaps, which is not defined. You set a function named overlaps but this is not how to add a jquery method to a jq object.

Try this: `$.fn.overlaps = function () {...};` And before reasking a question, next time check your console... This at least will fix the console error which apparently you still didn't try to fix

Comment: @roasted ah yes I see an error, I'll look into it. Also sorry for not checking console =S by bad entirely, I kinda forgot

Comment: @roasted I've fixed the console error with the help of your remark, ty! I'm afraid the main problem still remains tho, the console error log is now clear

Comment: Do you want to check whether it overlaps with *any* other of the elements or with *every* other element? And I've no idea why you would need `$(".Assemble_station").not(firstobj), secondobj)` for either of these.

Comment: @Bergi _Every_ other element as the script has to change the position of every overlapping element that chronologically comes second **with** the change of position affecting all future checks. The `.not(firstobj)` simply excludes the current element from the collection of elements to iterate over (as the current element initially also is part of that collection). It is however wrong I believe

Comment: Yeah it definitely seems like a mistake in the code, I must've gotten myself a bit confused when calling the .overlaps() function. Though it wasn't the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestions to improve your coding and debugging skills

Your updated code (in which you resolved the lack of the `overlaps` function) is failing because jQuery plugins are not supposed to be used in that way. Please consider reading about [creating jQuery plugins](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), and as much as you can about javascript debugging before trying to resolve this kind of problem.

Try to develop your debugging abilities by doing all of the following in the console after setting breakpoints (or using the `debugger` statement in your code):

- Play the relevant code step by step
- Check variables values
- Go thru the stacktrace
- Put commands in the console to see how the code behaves in that context

For instance, to resolve this problem I used some **jQuery into the console**:

```
> $(".Assemble_station") // this returned elements with [visibility:hidden] so I tried:
> $(".Assemble_station:visible") // but I got the same results, so I ended up using:
> $(".taskNameItem").remove() // then I checked again:
> $(".Assemble_station") // and now the results are different :)
```

And all these were done in the console without having to change the code. So you can really learn a lot by putting commands in the console while your code is in a breakpoint. But in jsFiddle, remember to change from the `<top frame>` to the `result` frame using the dropdown at the bottom of the console.

## The actual problems in your code

The problem with changing `overlaps` into a jQuery plugin, is that jQuery plugins can be called on many items at the same time. So it would be difficult to adapt it as a plugin to work properly, and you are better off using the original version.

But the problem with using the original function is that it works with normal HTML elements, but your elements are not so simple (because you hidden parts, and the containers have the positions while the contents the have the sizes). So I had to hack into the `getPosition` function inside `overlaps` to make it work with your weird HTML:

```
var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var obj = $( elem );
        var pos = obj.position();
        //HACK: weird HTML force me to use its first child's dimensions
        var child = obj.children(":first-child"); 
        var width = child.width();
        var height = child.height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }
```

Take a look at this new code on how to use the `overlaps` function (in the second `each`, I've removed not only the firstobj, but also every other object already tested in previous loops by using `i1 + 1` as starting point):

```
var stations = $('.Assemble_station');
stations.each(function(i1, firstobj) {
    stations.slice(i1 + 1).each(function(i2, secondobj) {
        if(overlaps(firstobj, secondobj)) {
            var obj1 = $(firstobj);
            var obj2 = $(secondobj);
            var objToMove = obj1.position().left >= obj2.position().left ? obj1 : obj2;
            var newTop = objToMove.position().top + 18;
            objToMove.css("top", newTop + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Your other problem is that several elements on your page are sharing `ID`s. If you give an element an id, it should be the only element with that id in the whole page. jQuery won't work as expected if you don't comply with this basic HTML assumption. I fixed this by removing (instead of hiding) the titles and the yellow bar (and doing it before getting the objects by id), so they won't interfere with the collision detection.

## The full solution

You can play with my jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/protron/NxWxU/8/

Comment: This answer is so good that I can't express my joy enough about it!
Not only did you solve my problem and showed me what it's fundamentals were, hereby expanding my knowledge and ability to deal with such problems and help others as such. 
You also pointed me in the right direction as to prevent further problems of a similar (or perhaps even broad) origin by pointing me to jQuery plugin creation documentation.

Comment: I'll be sure to ask others I know who have a stackoverflow acc to upvote your answer as to express my thanks/gratitude as much as I can. Oh and though I'm familiar with JSLint/JsHint, JSFiddle and the console in chrome/firebug, I can't say I've so far found a good article concisely covering in practice debugging for javascript, perhaps you have a bookmark you might recommend, one that if I had read would have probably prevented me from having the need to bother the community in the first place? I'd be sure to read it attentively with great interest!

Comment: I don't remember good articles about debugging. So take a look at my additions to the answer for some debugging hints :)